# Model not updated after database change

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im having problem that it seems my model not updated after database change. I have a list that each have button to approve or reject.

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LeaveProcess", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <input type="text" name="LvAppId" hidden value="@item.LvAppId">
    <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" name="AppVal" value=true data-confirm="are u sure?" >Approve</button></li>
    <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" name="AppVal" value=false >Reject</button></li>
}
```

When i press approve or reject button, the value of that submit button is go to controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LeaveProcess(string LvAppId, bool AppVal)
{
    DataChange.UpdateStatusFromAdmin(LvAppId, AppVal);
    TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Your Action Has Been Processed";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and update database column to "approved" or "reject".

```
public static void UpdateStatusFromAdmin( string LvAppId, bool AppVal)
{
    if (AppVal == true)
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE LeaveApps SET Status='Approved' WHERE LvAppId={0}", LvAppId);
    }
    else
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE LeaveApps SET Status='Rejected' WHERE LvAppId={0}", LvAppId);
    }
}
```

The database is updated (checked it with ssms), but when i reload the page, the value still not updated and i must restart debugging in visual studio to make it updated, what should i do? Thanks

Comment: How are you managing the lifetime your database context? are you doing something like: using(var db = new DatabaseContext()){// perform data access here }    see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj729737.aspx

Comment: Hmm i use it like this:
private static UserContext db = new UserContext();

and then call it like this:
var Employee = db.Employee.SqlQuery(strquery, Convert.ToInt32(EmpId)).FirstOrDefault();

is that wrong? and how is it related with my case?

Comment: If you are confident that that the query is correct and you can see changes being made to the backend using ssms but the changes aren't being reflected in your app.. I think that is a good indication that there is a problem with the context.  It looks like you aren't disposing of the context properly wrapping your data access inside a using statement as in the previous comment and the link would automatically dispose of it.... if that doesn't solve your problem I'd then focus on your query

Comment: If the database update code is working and the `Index.cshtml` view is not displaying the correct results, then its the code in the `Index()` method or the code in the view that is incorrect - you have not shown any of the relevant code.

Comment: @D.Mac wow it works now, looks like im using the context wrong before and after using it like you said now it works, thank you!

Comment: @Fimblutterr I've updated my comment to answer seeing as it solved your issue...Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are confident that that the query is correct and you can see changes being made to the backend using ssms but the changes aren't being reflected in your app.. I think that is a good indication that there is a problem with the context.

From your code it looks like you aren't disposing of the context properly.

Wrapping your data access inside a using statement like so:

```
 using(var db = new DatabaseContext())
 {
   // perform data access here 
 }
```

Will automatically dispose of it...

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj729737.aspx

If that doesn't solve your problem I'd then focus on your query

Answer (score 0):

Besides writing your values to the database, you do nothing with them.

Create an object of your model and call your view.

```
var model = new YourModel
{
    LvAppId = lvAppId, 
    AppVal = appVal
};

return View("Index", model);
```

Otherwise you have to make a call to the database to get your most recent values